# Preserve space in \@classoptionslist

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, class-options

I noticed that `\@classoptionslist` removes whitespace of the options. Is it possible to prreserve this whitespace?

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
%  \ProvidesClass{myclass}
%  \LoadClass[11pt]{scrartcl}
%\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ 12pt,   thing=Want Space ]{myclass}

\begin{document}
  Hello world.
  \makeatletter
  |\@classoptionslist|
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can use the raw option list. Or, if you want to setup a key-value option you can make use of the new keyval handler, see the newest latex news or Joseph's talk at tug 2022 https://youtu.be/jV9S2M0iEfo:

```
\documentclass[ 12pt,   thing=Want Space ]{myclass}

\begin{document}
  Hello world.
  
  \makeatletter
  |\@classoptionslist| 
  
  |\@raw@classoptionslist|
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]